# What happens to a jQuery Ajax post request if the page is closed while the request is running

Tags: php, json, ajax, upload

I am trying to understand how a jQuery ajax post request is handled if a window is closed while the request is running.

For example, I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  data :{ data: large_string, id: $('#theID').val() },
  url: "destination.php",
});
```

destination.php

```
echo $_POST['data'];
echo $_POST['id'];
```

If I close the window while the request is sending the data, I get the following error:

```
Undefined index: id
```

The large_string variable usually contains several MB of data, and it seems that if the window is closed, destination.php page is still sent the portion of the data parameter that was uploaded, but the id parameter is not even set.

Is there a way to check with PHP for a "canceled" or partial upload?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe just check the parameters are set, and validate them?

Comment: If you change the order of your fields so that `id` comes before `data`, then it should be sent first and decrease this. But as @HTMHell says you should always validate your incoming data.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!